# Why is the longer inheritance chain taking longer in my jsperf tsts

Tags: javascript, performance, prototype, performance-testing

I was trying to see what the performance cost of a long inheritance chain was, so I setup a jsperf test:
http://jsperf.com/prototype-inheritance-chain-cost

Here's the setup code:

```
Person = function (name) {this.name = name}
Person.prototype.title = function () {
return this.name
}
kinds = {"-1": Person};
instances = {"-1": new Person("john")}
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  kinds[i] = function (name) {this.name = name};
  kinds[i].prototype = new kinds[i-1];
  kinds[i].prototype[i] = function () {
    return this.name
  }
  instances[i + ''] = new kinds[i]("john")
}
test = function (i) {
  instances[i].title();
}
```

and here's the two test cases:

```
test("-1")
```

and

```
test(5)
```

However the first test is taking about an order of magnitude longer. I'm fairly certain that the first test should be faster, since it doesn't have to traverse the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple, it takes longer to access `instance[i]` in the `test` function than it does to access `title()`.

To fix the test I replaced the test function with two variables:

```
instanceOne = instances["-1"]
instanceFive = instances["5"]
```

Then the two test cases are simple:

```
instanceOne.title()
```

and

```
instanceFive.title()
```

The results are as you would expect:

No inheritance chain - 762,760,656 -    fastest
5 parents            - 717,293,580 - 6% slower

Comment: except that now it is not measuring much really - optimizing compiler when it hits the benchmark completely removes everything from the benchmarking loop (numbers in 700 000 000 ballpark usually means "benchmarking empty loop") and difference comes from difference before optimizations. -1 was just a very unfortunate choice - up until recently it was not treated equally well as other named fields by V8 - meaning access to it was very slow. it's fixed now too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll have to write a more complex test. Nice to know that the compiler is doing a lot of optimizations.